# Split NSString into multiple entries to NSMutableDictionary as key/value?

Tags: string, split, key, nsmutabledictionary

Ok, so I have this problem I have been spinning my head around for some time now.

I have a NSString like the following:

```
    NSString* foo = @"Brand: [Ford], Model: [Focus], Color: [black]";
```

which I would like to transfer into a NSMutableDictionary with Brand, Model, Color as keys and Ford, Focus, black as values (without the brackets [] ), but cannot seem to find any solution to this. How do I come about accomplishing the given scenario?

Edit:
Right now I use

```
NSArray *stringComponents = [foo componentsSeparatedByString@","];
```

which gives me an array like

```
stringComponents = [@"Brand: [Ford]", 
                    @"Model: [Focus]", 
                    @"Color: [black]",];
```

that I need to get into the syntax proposed by Sam, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDictionary is basically just an array that stores the values of the objects and keys, so you'd do something such as:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Brand", @"Model", @"Color", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ford", @"Focus", @"black", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                                                       forKeys:keys];
```

Comment: Ok, so right now I use

    NSArray *stringComponents = [foo componentsSeparatedByString@","];

to get an array with the pairs together, so it looks like
stringComponents =
  [@"Brand: [Ford]",
   @"Model: [Focus]",
   @"Color: [black]",]

and this I should somehow be able to get into your proposed syntax, but how?